# Can't map https://www.example.com to https://example.com

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

Trying to set up .htaccess to send requests for http://www.example.com to https://example.com.  Using an .htaccess procedure like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^http#(?:www\.)?(.+)$ 
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

does the right thing when dealing with http://www.example.com (going to https://example.com) and either https://example.com or http://example.com.  However, when I try using https://www.example.com, Chrome throws up "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

My SSL certificate apparently does not cover subdomains of example.com, so perhaps that's the problem? Is there any way to avoid unnecessary SSL processing on the www.example.com domain?

**Edit:**  Problem was that **www.example.com did not exist.**  After creating the sub-domain, the following htaccess code works:

```
# Map www.example.com to example.com    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#
# Ensure we are using https:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

[Still not sure whether the scope of my SSL cert. is an issue.]

Comment: If your certificate was delivered only for `example.com`, and without wildcard, it is fully normal that it can not be used for `www.example.com` and it will generate an error if used there.

Comment: Exactly.  But why is Apache/htaccess trying to validate the non-existent subdomain www.example.com?  If I can avoid that, the translation to https://example.com should work correctly, I would think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add the subdomain www.example.com.  (See edited question.)